# Can not log in to Stack Overflow using Yahoo account

Tags: support, login

I used to sign in with some OpenID, but since that went away, I have been using a Yahoo email address for a while. This was under "more options" or something like that on the log in page.

That seems to be gone now. So I made this new account.

How do I log in now?

Comment: I'm puzzled by the "new account" you mentioned (> 9 y.o.). Did the SO team manage to merge both already?

Comment: @CPHPython Since it's now a 6.9k user, that's the obvious conclusion. Meta posts tend to speed up stuff

Comment: @CPHPython There were some problems occurred with the transitioning of accounts where the automatic merge didn't work properly and left people with two accounts.  I had to fill in a support request for this myself, but the support team were really great and fixed the issue within a few hours.

Comment: Why were these options removed in the first place? Why weren't users notified? I didn't receive anything at least...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The Yahoo option was an OpenID login option that is no longer available as of July 25th.

If you can't login to the account, you'll need to use the [contact form](/contact) to get help regaining access by merging a new account into the old one. Include links to both profiles and the email address used on both profiles to expedite the process.

Comment: the contact form does not work on this site.

Comment: found the correct for on the main site.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the contact form from the main site, https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact. Or is the meta one the same thing?

Comment: @Lundin That page just takes you to the same form if you click the "contact us" link at the top, which is where all users would go because the other info is not relevant unless you use one of those products.

Comment: Rest in Peace, Yahoo. You had a good run buddy.

Comment: i got merged. so i can log in again. thanks

Comment: Hey someone might give me an answer, i'm logged in through openid thanks to cookies,  how the hell do i log in again on another browser?

Comment: @Marin The answer makes this clear that you need to use the contact form.

Comment: But i'm already "Logged In" ....  as pertaining to the question of "I can't log in"

Comment: The "forgot password" email still tells me I can login with my yahoo account: 'click "more login options" on the page'

Comment: @AdamBliss We're aware of that and it's on the roadmap to remove old OpenID credentials from the recovery emails.

Answer (score 27):

**There is better solution than accepted answer.**

Click on lost password option and provide your yahoo email address. You will be sent a link where you can restore you account. The link will say

> This email address is associated with an account, but no password is
>   associated with it yet, so it can't be used to log in.
>
> If you initiated this request, **set a password here.**

**Simply click on the link and provide new password**. Your account will be restored in no time.

Comment: Is this any different from Luxspes answer?

Comment: Actually same but he has given a recovery URL in the start but that URL is not needed. Simply choose last password option when logging in.

Comment: You are a life saver, thanks bro :)

Comment: Funny thing at the recovery email they STILL suggest to "click 'more login options' on the page"

Answer (score 5):

An easier way to gain access is to simply go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery write your @yahoo email and ask for password recovery. You will get an email saying that

> This email address is associated with an account, but no password is
>   associated with it yet, so it can't be used to log in

And a link to set a password. This way you can avoid having to create a new account and merging

Comment: thanks, i will try that.

Answer (score 1):

This may not directly related to the question, but once you got your yahoo login recover as @Hammad said, you can add multiple login method as below so you can move away from using yahoo mail:

[image]